# How can I add an additional user to publish snaphots to sonatype?

Tags: snapshot, sonatype

I have an account at sonatype.org where I can publish snapshots of our Maven project. What I would like to do is to give another sonatype user write access as well, so that he can publish the snapshots also. I have searched the sonatype manuals but found nothing about this.

Thanks and regards
Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File a request at https:/issues.sonatype.org in the "community support - open source hosting project".